# use flat sign in italics

Tags: luatex

How do I write a string of text containing a flat sign all in italics?

```
\textit{This is a ♭B}
```

When I do the above, I get an X where the flat is supposed to be.

Comment: It is a font issue. Can you post a MWE?

Answer (score 1):

The problem, is TeX cannot find the character
so a  glyph known as a `nodef` is printed. In your case as an X. Some fonts will give you
a question mark or a blank tofu. This means that the character
is missing in the font you specified.

One way to find out is to use the Last Resort font from Unicode
https://github.com/unicode-org/last-resort-font/releases/tag/14.000
and see in which block you can find the glyph. Normally you can find
a `NotoSans...` font supporting this range.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\lastresort{LastResort}
\begin{document}
\lastresort
\Huge
\textit{This is a ♭B}
\end{document}
```

As you can see from the image (I captured only the end of the text), this is
in the Miscellaneous Symbols range `U+2600-36FF`. `NotSansSymbols` font has the glyph. One could also use Lua in a `\directlua` command to get the glyph number or an online utility. The `LastResort` is a bit more fun. Thanks to Mr. Everson for providing the font.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you!

```
\def\flatit{\setbox0=\hbox{$\flat$}
\pdfliteral{q 1 0 .3 1 0 0 cm}\rlap{$\flat$}\pdfliteral{Q}\kern\wd0 }
\textit{This is a $\flatit$B}
```